# Putting a liquid tag inside an assign statement

Tags: liquid

I have a liquid if statement:

```
{% assign ql_posts = site.coding | reverse %}
```

But what if I want to change the "coding" in site.coding to the value of `{{page.cat}}`?

```
{% assign ql_posts = site.{{page.cat}} | reverse %}
```

doesn't seem to work.

Do you know a way to achieve this that will work?

For example, if the value of {{site.cat}} was design I would want the assign statement to look like this:

```
{% assign ql_posts = site.scratch | reverse %}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use square bracket notation:

`{% assign ql_posts = site[page.cat] | reverse %}`